# C++ undefined reference to class (1 header 2 cpp's)

Tags: c++, class, undefined

I am reading a book (C++ for dummies) as well as watching youtube videos to learn how to code.  I am currently struggling with very simple class functions.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include "Test.h"
using namespace std;

int x;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
    combat fight;
    cout << x;
    fight.dodmg();
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

**Test.h**   my header file with the class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef TEST_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_H_INCLUDED
class combat
{
public:
    int dodmg();
    void zero_out();
private:
    int x;
};


#endif // TEST_H_INCLUDED
```

**Test.cpp**  class functions

```
#include "Test.h"


int combat::dodmg()
{

    x = x - 5;
    return x;
}

void combat::zero_out()
{
    x = 20
}
```

I tried to make this very simplistic just to figure out how to work a class.
I included a lot of #includes just to try and make sure it wasn't something stupid like I needed strings.

I am not sure why but the videos I watched simply had the header say 
ifndef TEST_H (of their respective code, mine has an _INCLUDE as well, I tried deleting it and it still didn't work.

**My unfortunate errors**

on line 14 of main.cpp      fight.dodmg();      it says

```
\Beginning_Programming-CPP\Playing_with_class\main.cpp|14|undefined reference to `combat::dodmg()'|
```

then below that

```
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
```

Comment: First off, combat::x is not initialized, do this in the constructor

Comment: How are you compiling?  Is `Test.cpp` included in the list of files to compile?

Comment: Get a better C++ book and never watch youtube videos about coding.

Comment: My compiler is GNU GCC compiler.  One of them wasn't being compiled so I made sure all files are now being compiled and I still have the second error (first is taken care of though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you compiling this? I think this is an issue because you arent compiling your Test.cpp file. If you arent already, try compiling with the command:

**g++ main.cpp Test.cpp -o MyProgram**

**UPDATE:**

Few things, you dont have a closing statement to your #ifndef directive in Text.h, you will need a constructor to set the value of x so i added one to the combat class also you were missing a semicolon in the zero_out function. I added comments to all the lines I changed.

Okay try this:

Test.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef TEST_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_H_INCLUDED
class combat
{
public:
   combat(); // added constructor
   int dodmg();
   void zero_out();
private:
   int x;
};

#endif // closed #ifndef
```

Text.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

combat::combat() // implemented constructor
{
   x = 20;
}

int combat::dodmg()
{

   x = x - 5;
   return x;
}

void combat::zero_out()
{
   x = 20; // added ';'
}
```

Hope this helps,

Final edit: I dont think you really need your header guards in this scenario, you could remove the "#ifndef, #define, and the #endif" lines and not see a difference really

Comment: Which begs the next question, is the file named "Test.H" or "Test.h"

Comment: My compiler is GNU GCC compiler.  I checked the properties of the header and it wasn't being compiled O.o.  I checked the box and the first error went away, still have 'id returned 1 exit problem' though.
Compiling command? I am not familiar with that, not sure exactly how do I copy paste that or what?

Comment: you run that command in your terminal, in the directory where your source code is, i.e. where your main.cpp and test.cpp are. I would recommend if you are just starting to learn about C++ that you learn how to write the code in a text editor (such as sublime text), then compile it, and run it from the command line. It will give you a better understanding of how C++ works in a more general sense

Comment: Thanks for the multiple replies and in depth answers, really helped.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you provide the wrong arguments for the compiler. Your header file (Test.h) simply provides signatures for the methods, but the implementations are given in the source file (Test.cpp).

This is an important part of writing C++ (or C) code. Your compiler does not automatically search for source files, so you need to tell it where to look, e.g.:

> g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp Test.cpp -o main